# Android project uses two libraries that have same library project as dependency

Tags: java, android

I am building an API and I want to have different Android Library Projects and each of those libraries uses the same Android Project as library. So, it occurs an error when I am implementing a project that uses those two libraries, as both of them are importing the same Android Library Project.

The point is that I will develop many small libraries that import the same library, so the user could use for his project as many libraries as he wants.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio, Eclipse, or something else?

Comment: I was using Android Studio but I have changed to Eclipse and It's working now. I use in my project two libraries, and both of them import the same Android Library Project.

Comment: In Android Studio, if you were using artifacts for those libraries (e.g., `compile 'com.foo:artifact:19.0.2'` notation), usually it resolves redundant dependencies, and there are ways in Gradle to tell it to exclude certain nested dependencies from a `compile` directive.